# Set null data as undefined in a function?

Tags: javascript

This is a function being used in a ReactJS code base.

Right now, dates that are passed into this function as "null" rather than a string are being rendered as Dec 31, 1969. But no date should be showing if the date is passed in as null.

I want to modify my function below to check for null dates and set those dates to undefined. How should I do that?

```
var formatTheDate = function(dateString, dateFormat) {
    dateFormat = dateFormat || "MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm a";
    return moment.utc(new Date(dateString)).local().format(dateFormat);
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to set them to undefined? Why're you passing null dates to this function in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `dateString` before attempting to use it.

```
var formatTheDate = function(dateString, dateFormat) {
  dateFormat = dateFormat || "MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm a";
  return dateString 
    ? moment.utc(new Date(dateString)).local().format(dateFormat)
    : undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return undefined or null or your choice if the date isn't valid or returns the default date from unix time 0.

```
var formatTheDate = function(dateString, dateFormat) {
    var newDate = new Date(dateString);
    //optionally return a value instead of undefined here
    if(newDate == "Invalid Date" || newDate - new Date(null) == 0) return;
    dateFormat = dateFormat || "MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm a";
    return moment.utc(newDate).local().format(dateFormat);
};
```